# Some youtube videos are not working in my application

Tags: objective-c, youtube-api

My application is in swift and based on Youtube 360 Videos. I used this `'HCYoutubeParser'` `Objective-C` `Library`.
When I run application some videos are not loading.
I debug application but i didn't find any error.

Answer (score 0):

Videos might not be available at those link, this could be the reason that your videos are not loading.

Try using [YouTubePlayer](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player) written in swift.
Inspired by HCYoutubeParser and a great library to browse and watch Youtube videos on mobile.

Comment: videos are available at those links.

Comment: Try using library above.

Comment: same issue with this library.